Rootless Podman non-root user in container
I am trying to get the SWAG container from linuxerver.io (https://docs.linuxserver.io/general/swag/) to run with rootless podman (and not having a root user inside the container).
It seems that during the startup of the container some folders are being created inside the container that fail if that is not running with the necessary permissions.
Error: "mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/lib/nginx’: Permission denied"
This is not about mounting a volume or a folder on the host.
I did not find any useful tutorial or documentation on this topic. As the folder is inside the container it seems to be a too specific scenario.
Setup: RPi5, Ubuntu, Podman 5.0.3, Container creation via Quadlet
As the container does not start up at all, I also cannot log into it and do that manually.
Is there some way to get around that (e.g. by using a script in entrypoint that creates those folders as root)? The documentation of entrypoint that I found does not provide much help on if/how I could do that.
